# one-to-many mapping in grails throwing exception

Tags: grails

I am new to Groovy & Grails. I am working on one of the sample one-to-many relationship in Grails.

The below is the code.

```
class User {

    //properties
    String login
    String password
    String role

    //constraints and order of display of fields in UI
    static constraints = {
        login(blank: false, nullable: false, unique: true)
        password(blank: false, nullable: false, password: true)
        role(inList:["Admin", "Member"])
    }

    static hasMany = [posts : Post]
}


class Post {
    String content
    Date dateCreated

    static constraints = {
        content(blank: true)
    }

    static belongsTo = [user : User]
}
```

My Test class in Groovy

```
@TestFor(User)
class UserTests {

    void testUserToPost() {

        def user = new User(login: "joe", password: "joe", role:"Admin")
        user.addToPosts(new Post(content: "First"));
        user.addToPosts(new Post(content: "Second"));
        user.addToPosts(new Post(content: "Third"));
        user.save(flush: true)
        assertEquals 3, User.get(user.id).posts.size()

    }
}
```

While running the test class, getting following exception:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.library.forum.User.addToPosts() is applicable for argument types: (com.library.forum.Post) values: [com.library.forum.Post : (unsaved)]
Possible solutions: getPosts() at com.library.forum.UserTests.testUserToPost(UserTests.groovy:17)
```

Can anyone tell me where is the problem in code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Grails 2.1.4, there's a change in mock behavior because of performance issue. So you need to mock all associated entities of the mocked entity.

> See GRAILS-9637 - Due to a performance issue, @Mock no longer mocks
>   associated entities of the mocked entity. These have to be manually
>   specified. For example the following test will fail in 2.1.4 and
>   above:

```
@Mock(Author)
void testAddToBooks() {
    def a = new Author()
    a.addToBooks(new Book())
}
```

> To correct the above test you need to mock both Author and Book:

```
@Mock([Author, Book])
void testAddToBooks() {
    def a = new Author()
    a.addToBooks(new Book())
}
```

You can check this [reference](http://grails.org/2.2.1+Release+Notes).

Answer (score 1):

You need to mock all related domain classes. Change :

```
@TestFor(User)
class UserTests {
```

to

```
@TestFor(User)
@Mock(Post)
class UserTests {
```

If you need, the mock annotation support a list of classes, for example: `@Mock([Domain1, Domain2, Domain3])`